# Trouble installing tp link tl-wn821N V5 on 16.04

Tags: networking, 16.04, drivers, wireless, usb-modem

I am trying to install the USB wifi adapter: tp-link `TL-WN821N V5`.

I found a [driver](http://www.tplink.com/en/download/TL-WN821N.html#Driver) for the V5 version but it won't compile. In the manual of the Linux driver it is said that the driver is for: 14.04.01 with GCC v4.8.2.
My Linux edition is Ubuntu 16.04 with GCC v5.3.1.

I’ve run `lsusb` but my USB adapter wasn't listed:

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 2357:0107
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0781:5406 SanDisk Corp. Cruzer Micro U3
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c52e Logitech, Inc. MK260 Wireless Combo Receiver
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

I've run `lsusb` with and without the adapter plugged and without the adapter the line

The adapter works on Win 7 after installing the appropriate driver.

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 2357:0107
```

was missing.

Comment: With the adapter plugged in run `lsusb` then edit your question to include the results...sometimes there is no description for the device in lsusb results

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are in luck as I made a [commit](https://github.com/jeremyb31/rtl8192eu-linux-driver/commit/56ccb6b05cff08de1beddbbd03efdb36eff1416d) on github that enables that device.  We will use Mange's github as he included the commit and has dkms support so the driver will automatically get rebuilt for a kernel update.

You will need to have Secure Boot disabled if your computer is equipped with that feature

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic dkms git
git clone https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver.git
sudo dkms add ./rtl8192eu-linux-driver
sudo dkms install rtl8192eu/1.0
```

Reboot

If you do not have an active internet connection download https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver/archive/master.zip 
Transfer the file to the Ubuntu install, then extract it to the desktop.  Then in terminal

```
cd Desktop
sudo dkms add ./rtl8192eu-linux-driver
sudo dkms install rtl8192eu/1.0
```

Reboot

EDIT to add:

Now that you have installed it using make, I would suggest

```
cd Desktop/rtl8192eu-linux-driver
make clean
```

Before you install dkms with `sudo apt-get install dkms` and install the driver using the dkms commands

Comment: Do I need my computer to have an internet connection to get the code from github?

Comment: @AvishaiBarnoy Yes, you do.

Comment: Ok, i'll see what I can do about that.  I'm trying to install it on my pc and right now I don't have any internet connection. I'll probably be able to get a connection tomorrow.

Comment: I added some info about offline install, hopefully you have previously installed the build-essential package

Comment: Im trying to use dkms but it says the command not found

Comment: I've solved the problem by entering the folder and writing the commands: sudo make and then sudo make install. rebooted and that solved the problem. I'm writing this from my ubuntu install :)

Comment: You need to install `dkms` now and install it with `dkms`. Otherwise after each kernel update you will need to re-install the driver.

Comment: How can I add this driver to Ubuntu Live CD?